# Converting class component to functional component using react hooks (useRef)—how to avoid "undefined" error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to convert this code snippet which works as a class component to a functional component (using the react-rewards library).

Class component (working):

```
import { Checkbox } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Reward from "react-rewards";


  const config = {
    fakingRequest: false,
    angle: 90,
    decay: 0.91,
    spread: 100,
    startVelocity: 20,
    elementCount: 15,
    elementSize: 20,
    lifetime: 200,
    zIndex: 10,
    springAnimation: true,
    rewardPunish: "reward",
    type: "emoji",
  };
 

   export default class Playground extends Component {

     fakeRequest = () => {
         console.log(this);
         //@ts-ignore
         this.reward.rewardMe()
     };

     render() {
        const {
          type,
          fakingRequest,
          lifetime,
          angle,
          decay,
          spread,
          startVelocity,
          elementCount,
          elementSize,
          zIndex,
          springAnimation,
          rewardPunish,
        } = config;

       return (
         <div className="container">
           <Reward
             ref={(ref) => {
               //@ts-ignore
               this.reward = ref;
             }}
             type={"emoji"}
             config={{
               lifetime,
               angle,
               decay,
               spread,
               startVelocity,
               elementCount,
               elementSize,
               zIndex,
               springAnimation,
             }}
           >
             <Checkbox
               defaultChecked={false}
               onChange={this.fakeRequest}
             />
           </Reward>
         </div>
       );
     }
   }
```

This is what I have so far in the functional component, but it's not working, (the exact error message is: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'rewardMe' of undefined"):

```
import { Checkbox } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Reward from "react-rewards";

const FPlayGround: React.FC = () => {

    const rewardRef = React.useRef();

    const config = {
        fakingRequest: false,
        angle: 90,
        decay: 0.91,
        spread: 100,
        startVelocity: 20,
        elementCount: 15,
        elementSize: 20,
        lifetime: 200,
        zIndex: 10,
        springAnimation: true,
        rewardPunish: "reward",
        type: "emoji"
    };

      const fakeRequest = (rewardRef) => {
        rewardRef.reward.rewardMe();
      };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="container">
        <Reward ref={rewardRef} type={"emoji"} config={config}>
          <Checkbox
            defaultChecked={false}
            onChange={fakeRequest}
          ></Checkbox>
        </Reward>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
export default FPlayGround;
```

I think it has to do with the way I converted the "ref" portion, but I'm really not experienced enough to know for sure. Any help appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Swap `rewardRef.reward.rewardMe();` to `rewardRef.current.rewardMe()`

Comment: this didn't work unfortunately, the error message is still the same: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'rewardMe' of undefined"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The Ref

```
const rewardRef = React.useRef();
```

This line here creates a ref object whose `.current` value is initially `undefined`.  Because you didn't set any generic, typescript infers the value type based on the initial value and thus assumes that it will always be `undefined`.  So you cannot set any value to this ref!

```
Type 'MutableRefObject<undefined>' is not assignable to type 'Ref<RewardElement>'.
Type 'MutableRefObject<undefined>' is not assignable to type 'RefObject<RewardElement>'.
Types of property 'current' are incompatible.
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'RewardElement | null'.ts(2322)
```

The error on the ref actually tells us a bunch of information.

- We want a ref for a `RewardElement`
- Our initial value should be `null` instead of `undefined`

So we change our ref hook to this:

```
const rewardRef = React.useRef<RewardElement>(null);
```

We can get that type `RewardElement` from your imports (if it wasn't imported, you would use `typeof Reward`).

```
import Reward, {RewardElement} from "react-rewards";
```

### The Callback

The `onChange` handler for a `Checkbox` receives a change event as its argument.  We are not using that event, so we will use a function with zero arguments.  We do not want the ref to be an argument of the callback because that is not what it will be called with.

The value of a `ref` is stored on the property `.current`.  We initialized this to `null`, so `rewardRef.current` will either be a `RewardElement` or `null`.  We do not want to call `.rewardMe()` on `null` so that's why we use the nullish coalescing operator `?.` that others have suggested.

```
const fakeRequest = (): void => {
    rewardRef.current?.rewardMe();
};
```

Answer (score 1):

the actual properties of a DOM item you can catch with property "current" of ref:

```
 const fakeRequest = (rewardRef) => {
        rewardRef.current.reward.rewardMe();
      };
```

even if the object referenced is too deep, like:
`myBigObjRef.current.something.anothersomething`

you can use nullish coalescing

```
const fakeRequest = (rewardRef) => {
        rewardRef.current?.reward?.rewardMe();
      };
```

Comment: this mutes the error, but unfortunately nothing happens in the script :/...is the way I converted the ref correct? In the class component when I activate the onChange of the checkbox, it triggers the "rewardMe()" from the library, however using it the way in your answer just checks the box and nothing happens.

Comment: log the current object, and see what it has inside. See if you can call directly rewardMe() from current

Comment: I think for this one to be correct based off the class component you would want `rewardRef.current?.rewardMe();` but as @JulianoHenrique stated you should be able to see whats going on if you just log `rewardRef.current`.

Comment: yeah you're right @JacobSmit! Your initial comment was also correct, I just had to add the nullish coalescing as suggested here. Thanks for your input!